# Выбор позиции из списка сгенерированного ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Есть массив объектов (список мастеров), я вывожу его виде списка (`<li>`) с помощью директивы `ng-repeat`. При клике на элемент списка мне нужно поместить его в специальную переменную (прикрепляю мастера к заказу).